# jQuery .css() performances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I'm working on a website with several CSS transitions (quite heavy in resources) triggered with the jQuery method `.css()`.

I'm wondering if there's any difference of performance between the following ways of using `.css()`:

```
$(element).css('property','value');
$(element).css('property','value');
$(element).css('property','value');
```

the one I'm currently using:

```
$(element)
    .css('property','value')
    .css('property','value')
    .css('property','value')
;
```

and

```
$(element).css({
    'property':'value',
    'property':'value',
    'property':'value'
});
```

Here's a fiddle to show what I mean by “several CSS transitions (quite heavy in resources) triggered with the jQuery method `.css()`”: https://jsfiddle.net/uuezkd87/3/

Comment: I'm not a jQuery pro but I believe the last is best since it's only a single function call, even if it runs an internal loop.

Comment: ["jquery css chain vs array" (jsperf)](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-chain-vs-array/3)

Comment: From now on, I'll be voting to close as "asking us to recommend an off-site resource" any questions that can easily be answered by a test case on http://jsperf.com -- it's one thing to ask "*How* do I optimize this code?", and that's still on-topic, but asking "Which of *these three specific cases* is optimal?" isn't something we need to answer for you.

Comment: @Blazemonger Understand your point, I had never ran tests and considered it was quite a *hardcore* programmer thing, but now realize I could have made the test myself if I had been a bit more curious…

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for being the first one to bring jsperf to my knowledge

Comment: No worries -- my point is that this is something that can and should have been answered just with a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will definitely be the slowest, because you're creating the jQuery object from scratch each time. If you do this instead:

```
var $el = $(element);

$el.css('property','value');
$el.css('property','value');
$el.css('property','value');
```

... it should be the same as the second (chaining) option.

As for the difference between second and third options, the test linked in your comments says it barely makes any difference:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-css-chain-vs-array

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, none of these choices have a perceivable difference. That being said, unless your CSS values are calculated, I STRONGLY suggest you do your transitions using CSS transitions, and not JavaScript.

Here are the benefits of swapping classes:
- You access the DOM only once to add a class
- CSS transitions are GPU accelerated, which means 60fps transitions on most devices (especially better on lower power mobile devices)
- Separation of concerns... You leave the style and transitions in the CSS which is easier much easier to maintain than a growing JavaScript file

Comment: Also, refer to this: https://jsperf.com/jquery-css-vs-native-dom. jQuery's CSS method is EXTREMELY slow compared to native JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but that's only perceptible over hundreds of iterations. In a typical use case, the difference is imperceptible.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes, were on the same line. But if the developer in question wants to calculate and apply styles to something on the page multiple times (like parallax does), he's better off with native JavaScript rather than using jQuery's CSS method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).css('property','value');
$(element).css('property','value');
$(element).css('property','value');
```

$(element) will everytime fetch details of the element/selector from the document and it will reduce performance when compared to chaining

Answer (score 0):

I have run the following tests with jQuery (v. 2.2.1):

**A:**

```
$(element).css({
    'property': 'value',
    'property': 'value',
    'property': 'value'
});
```

- is the fastest

---

**B:**

```
$(element).css('property', 'value')
    .css('property', 'value')
    .css('property', 'value');
```

- is ~2 times slower than **A** in Chrome (v. 49.0.x for Windows)
- is ~2.5 times slower than **A** in Firefox (v. 41.0.x for Windows)
- is ~4.5 times slower than **A** in Explorer (v. 11.0.x for Windows)

---

**C:**

```
$(element).css('property', 'value');
$(element).css('property', 'value');
$(element).css('property', 'value');
```

- is ~2.5 times slower than **A** in Chrome (v. 49.0.x for Windows)
- is ~3.5 times slower than **A** in Firefox (v. 11.0.x for Windows)
- is ~5 times slower than **A** in Internet Explorer (v. 11.0.x for Windows)